# Reading big csv file C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to read quite big file with around 28 million of rows in the following way:

```
var jobs = new ActionBlock<string[]>((jobs) =>
        {
            //Some code
        });
        var pool = ArrayPool<string>.Shared;
        var items = pool.Rent(1000);

        using (FileStream fs = File.Open("test.csv", FileMode.Open))
        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024))
        {
            var count = 0;
            string s;
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                items[count] = s;
                if (count++ == 999)
                {
                    count = 0;
                    jobs.Post(items);
                }
            }

            jobs.Complete();
        }

        await jobs.Completion;
        pool.Return(items);
```

I'm trying to read it by means of ReadLine with some pre-defined buffer. Now it takes around 17 seconds in average. Each line contains alike lines:

> 100.1.8.hah,2017-05-16,00:00:00,0.0,1054102.0,0001493152-17-005364,form8-k.htm,200.0,3767.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,9.0,0.0,

How can I be sure is it slow and needs enhancements or it's quite appropriate ? If someone have some clues please let me know please ...

Comment: You could try increasing the buffer size from 1024 to 32768, but questions on improving already-working code may be better placed on [Code Review.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You don't need to use `BufferedStream` at all. `FileStream` and `StreamReader` are both already buffered. Also, why aren't you using asynchronous streams?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Then, in your `app.config`, set `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />`.

Finally, implement your function like so:

```cs
public async Task ReadCSV(string fileName)
{
    var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false,
    };

    using var csvReader = new StreamReader(fileName);
    using var csv = new CsvReader(csvReader, csvConfig);
    while (await csv.ReadAsync())
    {
        var field = csv.GetField("someField");

        // Do something with the field
    }
}
```